# Como guardar una variable en json con diferentes valores?

Tags: javascript, json

Me explico, tengo una variable que cambia depende del valor que le de un usuario, es decir mantiene el mismo nombre de variable, no se crea una nueva, pero su contenido cambia, ya que se recibe desde un input,por lo tanto cada vez que se sobreescribe, me gustaría guardarlo en formato json, por poner un ejemplo tenemos un input en el que un usuario puede escribir la palabra que desee, una vez escrita es asignada a esta variable por ejemplo "mesa", si a continuacion el usuario decide escribir en el input "variable que cambia", la variable es sobreescrita.
Para ello he realizado lo siguiente:

```
var cosa = "variable que cambia";
var contenido = 'valor=' + cosa;
var salida = {};
contenido.split(/\s*;\s*/).forEach(function (transformar) {
  transformar = transformar.split(/\s*=\s*/);
  salida[transformar[0]] = transformar.splice(1).join('=');
});
var json = JSON.stringify(salida, null, 4);
console.log(json);
```

de esta forma guarda lo siguiente, pero si sobreescribo solo guarda el ultimo resultado:

```
{
   "valor":"variable que cambia",
}
```

Lo que yo pretendo es que cada vez que la variable cosa reciba un nuevo valor se guarde en el json. Algo así como:

```
{
  variable1: [
    {
      "valor":"variable que cambia",
    },
  ],
  variable2: [
    {
      "valor":"hola mundo",
    },
  ],
  variable3: [
    {
      "valor":"prueba3",
    },
  ],
};
```

Como podría realizar esto? No entiendo como aplicar al json el resultado de la variable y cada resultado sobreescrito a continuación, ya que necesito ir guardando cada vez que se sobrescribe mi variable, para poder trabajar con caa variacion de esta misma variable posteriormente.

Answer (score 4):

Yo optaría por usar una lista (`Array`), a la cual le vas añadiendo los valores de acuerdo a como van cambiando. Esto incluso te permitiría agregar un campo de tipo `Date` que podría servir como `timestamp` indicando el momento en que el valor fue recibido, o cualquier otro campo que consideres necesario aparte del campo `valor`. Recuerda que toda lista o `Array` es un JSON válido.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let valoresCambiantes = [
  "esto es un valor",
  "otro valor",
  "valor adicional",
  "último valor",
  "miento, este si es el último"
]

let lista = [];

valoresCambiantes.forEach(valor => lista.push({ valor }));

let json = JSON.stringify(lista, null, 4);
console.log(json);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esto te produce un documento JSON cuyo contenido es una lista de objetos con la estructura: `{ "clave": "valor" }`.

Para acceder a los elementos de esta lista, es tan sencillo como analizar el JSON con `JSON.parse()` y volcar el resultado en una variable que será un `Array` de objetos. Podrás acceder acada objeto usando la notación de corchete de los tipo `Array`:

```
let miArray = JSON.parse(json);
//objeto 1:
console.log(miArray[0].valor); // "esto es un valor"
```

En cuanto a la forma en la que planteas el resultado en tu pregunta, es algo que no recomiendo, debido a que las claves llamadas `variable1`, `variable2`, ... `variableN` no seguirían un patrón fácilmente reconocible.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

De acuerdo a lo [aclarado por tí en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56617592#56617592), deseas poder almacenar un valor introducido por el usuario en una Cookie, de tal manera que si el usuario introduce otros valores, los mismos sean añadidos a esta Cookie y no se sobreescriban. A la vez deseas darle formato JSON a los valores almacenados en dicha Cookie.

Vamos a hacer un pequeño ejercicio mental sobre lo que deseamos lograr y así tal vez demos con una solución adecuada.

**JSON**

De [JSON - Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), tenemos que JSON es un formato de texto para el intercambio de datos. Tan sencillo como eso.

Nos permite enviar y recibir datos con una sintaxis parecida a la notación de [Objeto de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object).

Ahora bien, si lo que deseas almacenar en tu cookie es un texto en formato JSON que contenga los valores previos más el actual, vuelvo a insistir en que uses una lista.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('botonId');
const guardarValor = event => {
  const valor = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
  if(!valor) return;
  let lista = [];
  if(Cookies.get('miCookie') {
    lista = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('miCookie'));
  }
  lista.push(valor);
  Cookies.set('miCookie', JSON.stringify(lista));
};

boton.addEventListener('click', guardarValor);
```

Con esto implementado, puedes ir almacenando valores en la cookie llamada `miCookie` que siempre tendrá una lista con todos los valores introducidos por el usuario.

Como el `snippet` de StackOverflow no permite trabajar con Cookies, vamos a hacer un *Mockup* (maqueta o modelo) de este objeto para representar su fucnionalidad.

```js
/**
 * La siguiente Clase imita el comportamiento del
 * Objeto Cookie del Navegador
 */
 
class CookieClass {

  #cookies;
  
  constructor() {
    this.#cookies = {};
  }
  
  set(name, value) {
    if(!name || !value) return;
    if(typeof name !== 'string') return;
    this.#cookies[name] = value;
  }
  
  get(name) {
    if(!name || typeof name !== 'string') return;
    return this.#cookies[name];
  }
}
 
// Ahora podemos instanciar nuestro objeto de Cookie básico
const Cookie = new CookieClass();

 
// funcionalidad para añadir cosas a nuestra cookie
const boton = document.getElementById('botonId');

const guardarValor = event => {
  const valor = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
  if(!valor) return;
  let lista = [];
  if(Cookie.get('miCookie')) {
    lista = JSON.parse(Cookie.get('miCookie'));
  }
  lista.push({ valor });
  Cookie.set('miCookie', JSON.stringify(lista, null, 4));
  // mostramos los datos almacenados
  let datos = Cookie.get('miCookie');
  document.getElementById('resultadoId').innerText = datos;
};

boton.addEventListener('click', guardarValor);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ml-1 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for="inputId">Valor:</label>
  <input class="ml-1"placeholder="Escriba algo..." id="inputId">
  <button class="ml-2"type="button" id="botonId">Guardar</button>
</div>
<div class="container mt-2">
  <pre id="resultadoId"></pre>
</div>
```

De esta forma, cada vez que se ejecuta la acción de `click` sobre el botón, se almacena lo que el usuario ha introducido en el campo `input`, en un texto con formato `JSON`, que será almacenado en la `cookie` con nombre `miCookie`.

En el código he implementado un elemento [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre) para mostrar el texto del JSON (sin usar `parse`), para que veas la estructura que se almacena en la cookie.

Comment: mmm el problema es que no puedo asignar las variables que yo quiera, sino que primero recibo un valor en la variable cosa y luego en otro momento cualquiera puedo recibir otro valor o no, por lo tanto debe ir añadiendo si recibe. la variable cosa siempre es la misma pero se sobreescribe, la variable "cosa" es por ponerle un nombre de ejemplo, en este caso yo tengo asignada una cookie que se recibe en esta variable, por lo tanto cuando la cookie cambia de valor necesito guardarla y seguir añadiendo, para poder despues selecionar un valor de mi json y emparejar datos con la seccion de la cookie.

Comment: es un tanto mas complejo, pero yo he intentado preguntarlo de forma sencilla, por lo tanto no se muy bien como enfocar mi código para ir reasignando y creando mas fragmento de json

Comment: Recibes un valor en un variable, ese nombre de variable sería la clave en el JSON, su valor sería el valor para esa clave, por eso harías algo como:  `lista.push({ cosa })`. Si el contenido de la variable cambia sólo tienes que volver a ejecutar `lista.push({ cosa })`. Así de sencillo me parece que resuelves el problema.

Comment: mm comprendo y como guardo si son diferentes? quiero decir ahi hay un array hecho, si coloco por ejemplo let valoresCambiantes = [cosa] si recibo un valor diferente se aplica? es que esto lo que mas me cuesta entender.

Comment: lo he probado pero siempre reemplaza el valor de  la ultima variable recibida

Comment: Vas a tener que mostrar cómo recibes esa variable y qué sentido la misma cambia con el tiempo. Edita tu pregunta o entra al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). Saludos

Comment: Listo he ido al chat, es que mi problema principal es como guardar la variable primera y lo que se sobrescribe cada vez.Por eso la pregunta.

Comment: Hola disculpa la tardanza en responder! por alguna razon me da error Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data en la linea -->   lista = JSON.parse(cookie); he usado el codigo un tanto diferente ya que debia adecuarlo a mi código lo he puesto dentro de la funcion addeventlistener de un boton en una página distinta al input donde se recibe la cookie usando solo let lista = [];
  if(cookie) {
    lista = JSON.parse(cookie);
  }
  lista.push(cookie);
  Cookies.set('miCookie', JSON.stringify(lista));

Comment: @WinterIsBack eso sucede únicamente si has alterado el strin texto del json parse; podes antes de hacerle parse imprimirlo en la consola para verificar que el texto tenga la forma correcta